# Require login to be able to see anything on wiki server?

Tags: osx-server, permission, login, server.app

In addition to having wikis, the wiki server built into OS X Server also allows users to host blogs and personal file storage.  By default, it appears that these functions are enabled, even if you are not currently logged in.  Is there a way to lock down the wiki server so that when someone goes to companyserver.com/wiki it doesn't give them access to anything but a login prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4156010 I have not tried it.